# Salesforce ActivityHistories ActivityType returns garbage

Tags: api, salesforce

I'm running this query to get all activities associated with opportunities:

```
SELECT (SELECT Id, Subject, ActivityType, ActivityDate, OwnerId, CreatedBy.Name,Description FROM ActivityHistories) FROM Opportunity
```

This is what I get:

```
...
"records": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "type": "ActivityHistory",
                        "url": "/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/ActivityHistory/00Ti000000B72QWEAZ"
                    },
                    "Id": "00Ti000000B72QWEAZ",
                    "Subject": "test Call 2",
                    "ActivityType": "1_",
                    "ActivityDate": "2011-07-05",
                    "OwnerId": "005i00000013T0TAAU",
                    "CreatedBy": {
                        "attributes": {
                            "type": "User",
                            "url": "/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/User/005i00000013T0TAAU"
                        },
                        "Name": "John Fiedler"
                    },
                    "Description": "test comment"
                },
...
```

The ActivityType field is "1_", where it should be a picklist of "Call", "Event", etc. Any suggestiopns?

Comment: any update on this, i am also getting the same problem today ?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta sorry I've stopped working on this.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/56513/266 found a fix, and posted it in the attached stackexchange thread.